# Does a hybrid app GUI decrease the overall performance of the app compared to a native gui?

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

I just started playing with Tizen and I've read that the native apps bring a performance improvement - being closer to the hardware.
As building a GUI for a native app is a pain in the NAS, how large would be the performance loss by writing a hybrid app (so Web GUI with native service)?
(Use case: read sensor data as fast as possible, calculate stuff and make the results user friendly)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both web and native app performance now a days are not an issue anymore, with the latest hardware.

If you think Designing GUI in Native is a pain in NAS then Web projects with TAU framework should be fine.

Also you can find lots of sample apps in IDE web projects, hope trying those will give you some guidance.

Comment: I am using a Samsung Gear S2 for development and the GUI should look nice, with smooth transitions but in the same time I need to sample sensor data every 10ms continuously and do this as reliable as possible.   My concern is that if the GUI needs too many resources then the sampling will not be constant meaning that I will get some data every 10ms and during the GUI transitions I might have it with 20ms or more.

Comment: I have developed web apps that uses sensor reading and they turned out just fine. The GUI I had to develop was good looking and not that heavy (that's the way I designed it). My suggestion to you is to try a web app just the way you want and see for yourself, I think you will like it. If that does not work for you you can always go for Native app.

Comment: One more thing, you can try the GUI builder in Tizen IDE, hope that will solve your designing issue. LINK:    https://developer.tizen.org/development/getting-started/native-application/application-development-process/creating-application-uis-ui-builder